# How can I position my QLabel widgets correctly in PySide

Tags: pyside

I set up my script and I am building my GUI, but I am having some trouble positioning my QLabels correctly over the corresponding attribute columns beneath them. I have tried inserting spacing and adding stretch between the labels, but its tough to get them positioned correctly, and I am worried they will shift as the window variables change. What is the best strategy?

[image]

Comment: provide a [mcve]

Comment: Use a QGridLayout ("Layout in a grid" button in the toolbar)